# Agora & Unity. How make audience for one Broadcaster

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io, audience

How todo this task:
I have a task, I need one person only to be able to broadcast all connected their web camera. ie. other connected do not broadcast video, and see only one (admin).

I just trying to studie it.
Please help help help!

And if it can, disable voice stream for broadcaster and audience.

how i must modified in TestHelloUnityVideo.cs in Agora demo scene?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

using agora_gaming_rtc;
using agora_utilities;


// this is an example of using Agora Unity SDK
// It demonstrates:
// How to enable video
// How to join/leave channel
// 
public class TestHelloUnityVideo
{


    // instance of agora engine
    private IRtcEngine mRtcEngine;

    


    // load agora engine
    public void loadEngine(string appId)
    {
        // start sdk
        Debug.Log("initializeEngine");

        if (mRtcEngine != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Engine exists. Please unload it first!");
            return;
        }

        // init engine
        mRtcEngine = IRtcEngine.GetEngine(appId);

        // enable log
        mRtcEngine.SetLogFilter(LOG_FILTER.DEBUG | LOG_FILTER.INFO | LOG_FILTER.WARNING | LOG_FILTER.ERROR | LOG_FILTER.CRITICAL);
    }

    public void join(string channel)
    {
        Debug.Log("calling join (channel = " + channel + ")");


        if (mRtcEngine == null)
            return;
        
        // set callbacks (optional)
        mRtcEngine.OnJoinChannelSuccess = onJoinChannelSuccess;
        mRtcEngine.OnUserJoined = onUserJoined;
        mRtcEngine.OnUserOffline = onUserOffline;

        // enable video
        mRtcEngine.EnableVideo();
        // allow camera output callback
        mRtcEngine.EnableVideoObserver();

        // join channel
        mRtcEngine.JoinChannel(channel, null, 0);

        // Optional: if a data stream is required, here is a good place to create it
        int streamID = mRtcEngine.CreateDataStream(true, true);
        Debug.Log("initializeEngine done, data stream id = " + streamID);
    }

    public string getSdkVersion()
    {
        string ver = IRtcEngine.GetSdkVersion();
        if (ver == "2.9.1.45")
        {
            ver = "2.9.2";  // A conversion for the current internal version#
        }
        else
        {
            if (ver == "2.9.1.46")
            {
                ver = "2.9.2.2";  // A conversion for the current internal version#
            }
        }
        return ver;
    }

    public void leave()
    {
        Debug.Log("calling leave");

        if (mRtcEngine == null)
            return;

        // leave channel
        mRtcEngine.LeaveChannel();
        // deregister video frame observers in native-c code
        mRtcEngine.DisableVideoObserver();
    }

    // unload agora engine
    public void unloadEngine()
    {
        Debug.Log("calling unloadEngine");

        // delete
        if (mRtcEngine != null)
        {
            IRtcEngine.Destroy();  // Place this call in ApplicationQuit
            mRtcEngine = null;
        }
    }


    public void EnableVideo(bool pauseVideo)
    {

        if (mRtcEngine != null)
        {
            if (!pauseVideo)
            {
                mRtcEngine.EnableVideo();
            }
            else
            {
                mRtcEngine.DisableVideo();
            }
        }
    }

    // accessing GameObject in Scnene1
    // set video transform delegate for statically created GameObject
    public void onSceneHelloVideoLoaded()
    {

        // Attach the SDK Script VideoSurface for video rendering
        GameObject quad = GameObject.Find("Quad");
        if (ReferenceEquals(quad, null))
        {
            Debug.Log("BBBB: failed to find Quad");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            quad.AddComponent<VideoSurface>();
        }

        GameObject cube = GameObject.Find("Cube");
        if (ReferenceEquals(cube, null))
        {
            Debug.Log("BBBB: failed to find Cube");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            cube.AddComponent<VideoSurface>();
        }
    }

    // implement engine callbacks
    private void onJoinChannelSuccess(string channelName, uint uid, int elapsed)
    {
        Debug.Log("JoinChannelSuccessHandler: uid = " + uid);
        GameObject textVersionGameObject = GameObject.Find("VersionText");
        textVersionGameObject.GetComponent<Text>().text = "SDK Version : " + getSdkVersion();
    }

    // When a remote user joined, this delegate will be called. Typically
    // create a GameObject to render video on it

   
    private void onUserJoined(uint uid, int elapsed)
    {
        Debug.Log("onUserJoined: uid = " + uid + " elapsed = " + elapsed);
        // this is called in main thread
        
        // find a game object to render video stream from 'uid'
        GameObject go = GameObject.Find(uid.ToString());
        if (!ReferenceEquals(go, null))
        {
            return; // reuse
        }
        
        // create a GameObject and assign to this new user
        VideoSurface videoSurface = makeImageSurface(uid.ToString());
        if (!ReferenceEquals(videoSurface, null))
        {

            // configure videoSurface
            videoSurface.SetForUser(uid);
            videoSurface.SetEnable(true);
            videoSurface.SetVideoSurfaceType(AgoraVideoSurfaceType.RawImage);
            videoSurface.SetGameFps(30);
        }
    }

    public VideoSurface makePlaneSurface(string goName)
    {
        GameObject go = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Plane);

        if (go == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        go.name = goName;
        // set up transform
        go.transform.Rotate(-90.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        float yPos = Random.Range(3.0f, 5.0f);
        float xPos = Random.Range(-2.0f, 2.0f);
        go.transform.position = new Vector3(xPos, yPos, 0f);
        go.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.25f, 0.5f, .5f);

        // configure videoSurface
        VideoSurface videoSurface = go.AddComponent<VideoSurface>();
        return videoSurface;
    }

    private const float Offset = 100;
    public VideoSurface makeImageSurface(string goName)
    {
        GameObject go = new GameObject();

        if (go == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        go.name = goName;

        // to be renderered onto
        go.AddComponent<RawImage>();

        // make the object draggable
        go.AddComponent<UIElementDragger>();
        GameObject canvas = GameObject.Find("Canvas");
        if (canvas != null)
        {
            go.transform.parent = canvas.transform;
        }
        // set up transform
        go.transform.Rotate(0f, 0.0f, 180.0f);
        float xPos = Random.Range(Offset - Screen.width / 2f, Screen.width / 2f - Offset);
        float yPos = Random.Range(Offset, Screen.height / 2f - Offset);
        go.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(xPos, yPos, 0f);
        go.transform.localScale = new Vector3(3f, 4f, 1f);

        // configure videoSurface
        VideoSurface videoSurface = go.AddComponent<VideoSurface>();
        return videoSurface;
    }
    // When remote user is offline, this delegate will be called. Typically
    // delete the GameObject for this user
    private void onUserOffline(uint uid, USER_OFFLINE_REASON reason)
    {
        // remove video stream
        Debug.Log("onUserOffline: uid = " + uid + " reason = " + reason);
        // this is called in main thread
        GameObject go = GameObject.Find(uid.ToString());
        if (!ReferenceEquals(go, null))
        {
            Object.Destroy(go);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a code of demo scene for Unity.

Answer (score 0):

### Broadcast Mode

> I need one person to broadcast from their connected web camera that all other users can see, and other connected users don't broadcast video.

Agora's default call state is "Communication Mode" (many to many),  which is essentially a group video call where everyone can see/hear everyone else on the call.
What you are looking for is our ["Broadcast Mode"](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/product_live?platform=All%20Platforms) (one to many).

First you have to [SetChannelProfile()](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/unity/classagora__gaming__rtc_1_1_i_rtc_engine.html#a178b60cc7d6a803fae6c7026e80d85c8) to [CHANNEL_PROFILE_LIVE_BROADCASTING](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/unity/namespaceagora__gaming__rtc.html#a279b0b929ee1f352fb3a6d315db781b0) which will set up the Agora channel for a Broadcaster -> Audience setup.

Then you have to specify who is the Broadcaster, and who is the Audience -- the default role is Audience.
Call [SetClientRole()](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/unity/classagora__gaming__rtc_1_1_i_rtc_engine.html#a8b7ca7e2069f50b62c2547fb01f5b1fa) to specify who you want to be your [BROADCASTER](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/unity/namespaceagora__gaming__rtc.html#a6e135c9ade887e0d7b137bd5133f30ea),

---

### Disable Voice Stream

> And if I can, disable voice stream for broadcaster and audience.

You can indeed!
[SetDefaultMuteAllRemoteAudioStreams()](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/unity/classagora__gaming__rtc_1_1_i_rtc_engine.html#af9c3e50a88fd7408d9229f2fa54dbe11) will disable all incoming audio streams from every user. If you'd like to unmute a specific person, call [MuteRemoteAudioStream(userUIDToUnmute, false)](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/unity/classagora__gaming__rtc_1_1_i_rtc_engine.html#a54b2f6ca418965113ee6797eb611be2f)

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH!